# How to make multiple button with dropdown and send to other site?

Tags: php

ok , i have url shortening service site, i wrote the script based on phurl project, but it only support 1 domain, and i need 2 or more domains. so i think using dropdown to replace the button and each button send the data to different site, how can i do that? is that possible?

here's the box & the button code:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
                                        <label for="url">Enter web address (URL) here:</label><br />    
<input id="url" type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_GET['url']) ?>" />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Shorten" /></p>
```

you can have a try at http://pndk.tk/ , and i wanna add 3 domains more, with the same script.

Comment: lol on "You enjoy, I enjoy: Donate" haha

Comment: what do you actually want? Do you want to POST to different URLS regarding on what user will select from dropdown?